# list of iphone application under single application

Tags: iphone

i am developing an application in iPhone, where i need to implement my 5 application under single application.

i.e. i have 5 different application's source code and i need to develop single application which will list these 5 application icon(shortcut) to each. on clickkin

i tried Google but i cant find anything related to that.

i find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054788/how-can-i-combine-multiple-iphone-applications-in-to-one-application) but i don't know "UI presentation".

if any one knows about than please help.

Thanks.

Comment: By "UI presentation", that poster was referring to the fact that you need to design or come up with a solution that enables a user to easily switch between the main views of each app, within the primary app container.

Comment: @Krypton : Thanks.. i had miss read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at UITabBar which provides a convenient way to switch between Application views - and works best with up to 5 top-level views.  You can then dig into your 'separate' applications from each top-level Tabbed view by incorporating a UINavigationBar into each.