# how to add one or more apps in single app

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have a situation,

where more than two separate iOS apps together to form a single app. The apps have entirely separate to each other and concept is money based program. Is there any way **press a button and one project would run. And the press another and another project would run.**

In App Purchase will help for this question, like this

[Notification center label http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/12/v4v4.png](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/12/v4v4.png)

Second, How to update that single app when more than one app was incorported and how to show notification on top of the app. Is there is any tutorial for this question.

Please help me, I saw one or two solution but i didn't get any idea for this question.

Comment: To my knowledge, i think you cant do that directly.check this link ,might give some hints to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054788/how-can-i-combine-multiple-iphone-applications-in-to-one-application

Comment: could i use **In App Purchase** for this solution?

Answer (score -1):

It is easy. Just use an open url scheme and give the link to the other iOS application that you wish to open from within your application.

Refer to "Communicating with Other Apps" in the following developer documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html

NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"itunesLinkToOtherProject"];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:myURL];

To come back to your app from the other application, use a similar custom URL scheme for your app within the other application. Thus you will be able to go from your app to the other app and vice versa.